# Why do I get an OutOfMemoryError when load-testing a Swagger-Webservice

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator

We have developed a MicroService which is accessed by a secondary system. Both systems use a Swagger/OpenApi API to communicate with one-another. We generate the client as "java" (underlying okhttp-Client).

When we are load-testing the system after some time we get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread` on the client, although the system has plenty of memory configured (via -Xmx).
How can we avoid this? What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenApi generates the "java"-Client such that each instance of `ApiClient` wraps one instance of `OkHttpClient`. The documentation of `OkHttpClient` states, that each instance creates a `ThreadPool` as well as a cache. It also states, that `OkHttpClient`-Instances should be shared among multiple requests.

If you do not do this and generate one `ApiClient` per call, you will sort of leak `Thread`s. These are recovered, once a garbage-collection eliminates the unused `ApiClient` instances, however, if your system is configured with plenty of memory, this gc-call might not occur frequently enough and you might end up with more requested native threads, than the underlying os can deliver.

The solution is to re-use `ApiClient`-instances within your application or switch to a client based e.g. on Spring `RestTemplate`.

For those curious: `OkHttpClient` seems to reserve the threads to deal with async http/2 requests - which is kind of overkill, if your application does not actually do async calls.